# C++: Is it possible to friend all instances of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class called RenderShader, I also have a class called Render. I would like to have all instances of the RenderShader template class to be friends with Render. Also the user is allowed to make their own RenderShader instances so it's not possible to list all of them in the main header file. For Example:

```
template<class vertdef>
class RenderShader
{
public:
.....
};

class Render
{
    friend class RenderShader;
public:
    ....
};
```

The syntax "friend RenderShader" is wrong, is there a correct syntax for what I would like to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
class Render
{
    template<class vertdef>
    friend class RenderShader;
public:
    ....
};
```

Comment: That worked on 3 of the 4 systems I am compiling my code with: It worked on VS2010 PC, VS2010 XBox360, Chrome Native-Client. It didn't work on using g++ (installed with Dev-C++) for the GP2XWiz.

Comment: @KPexEA : Last I saw, Dev-C++ still comes with GCC 3.4.x, which is pretty close to ancient at this point. Try updating MinGW to the current version (4.6.x).

Comment: @KPexEA Did you forward declare the templated class? (same syntax as friend declaration)

Comment: @Ian Haggerty: Yes it is forward declared, it's probably just a really old compiler. I will update it asap. Thanks!

Comment: No need to forward declare it.